# Use the YouTube Iframe API's loadVideoById without automatically playing

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

I'm using the [YouTube Iframe API][1] to switch between videos in a player using the [loadVideoByID][2] method, but it always plays the video after loading. I don't want it to automatically play.

```
player.loadVideoById({
  videoId: 'abcd1234'
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that function that you are looking for is :

```
player.cueVideoById({
  'videoId':'abcd1234'
})
```

This function will wait until you say it can play . Cheers :)